# Code for API in smartsheets on demand batch export

Tags: node.js, rest, node-red, smartsheet-api

I'm fairly noob on  the whole RESTful/SOAP arena, I've been looking around for samples using node.js to trigger a Rest or SOAP API to be able to export a batch of smartsheets to excel

I already got a sample for google drive export but its not quite what I need

I'm not sure how to search for code or samples using microsoft excel export and then batch from a list of files or even a smartsheets workspace

I expect a folder with all the exported excel files in the server at a specified location. I'm also thinking of how this could be done using node-red instead as an alternative, what is the suggested path of least resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a GET Sheet request via the Node.js SDK and have the results returned as an Excel file:
https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#get-sheet-as-excel-pdf-csv
Note, this requires the Sheet ID and is done as a request for each sheet. There isn't a method to request a batch export of a collection of sheets via the API. You would need to gather a list of Sheet IDs and loop through it to request each one as an Excel file while storing them in your desired location.
You could do a [GET Workspace](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#get-workspace) request to get a list of all of the sheets in a workspace for creating your list of Sheet IDs. You could use the [List Sheets](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#list-sheets) request to get a list of all of the sheets you have access to as well. Both of those requests are supported by the Node.js SDK.